# Run "Connect-MsolService" without user-interactivity and take Windows authentication for Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-powershell

I want to run command "Connect-MsolService" on powershell but without the user interaction. It should take Windows authentication. Also i can't save my password in any external text file to do the authentication.

I want it to be authenticated by currently logged in Windows server credential and authenticate.
Is there any possible way to do that in Powershell?

Comment: Actually the MSOnline powershell module is old, Customers are encouraged to use the newer AzureAD module, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0). Will you accept to use the AzureAD module? Or what operations will you do with MSOnline module?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the command as below to login with non-interactive way, make sure the user account is not MFA-enabled.

```
$azureUsername="user@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<Password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureUsername , $azurePassword)
Connect-MsolService -Credential $psCred
```

Comment: But i don't want to save the password anywhere : not in any file or in powershell script.
I want the authentication should be Windows authentication instead of saving password in powershell script or in any external encrypted  file